# How to separate the elements from a nested list? Eg;- [1,[2,3]], I need to get 1,2,3 printed..?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Hi I was working out with nested lists in python and found this to be a big problem. I know we should go with recursive functions but unable to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

If you have list of list -e.g max depth is 1 then you can use the following code:

```
lVals = [1,[2,3]]

res = []
for i in lVals:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        res.extend(i)
    else:
        res.append(i)

print res
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks everybody me got it now...

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(li):
    if not isinstance(li, list):
        return [li]
    rv = []
    for ll in li:
        rv.extend(flatten(ll))
    return rv


print flatten([1,2,3,4])
print flatten([1,[2,3],3,4])
print flatten([1,[2,[3,4,5]],3,4])
print flatten([1,[2,[3,4,5]],3,[]])
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```